# How to assign separate material to separate mesh

Tags: modeling, materials

i have the base mesh and with the bool tool addon i have some difference, slice operation and it created separate mesh. When i try to give different material to the mesh. it gives the material complete model. if i delete the material from particular mesh it delete complete material from all the mesh. I dont want to apply all the boolean operation. How to give material to separate mesh.

**Demo file**

[image]

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpuNY.jpg)

This is what i did so far
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zacym.jpg

Comment: I think you're talking about separate objects, maybe share your file

Comment: @moonboots this is what i did so far https://imgur.com/a/t1RpCvR

Comment: yes that's weird, the other objects should keep their material, could you share your file so that we test?

Comment: @moonboots plz check question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your objects are linked-duplications, it doesn't look like because you gave them different booleans. So any modification on one of them (material or mesh) will be replicated on the other. If you want to keep their mesh linked but want to have separate materials, choose *Object* instead of *Data* in the *Material* panel:

[image]

If you want to completely separate them, go in the *Object menu > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks it work with the object.

Comment: cannot add material to the solid modifier. I have selected the color in index offset. Yet to cant assign on solid modifier

Comment: you mean the Solidify material? You need to use the Material Index Offset, and the values are linked to the material order in the Material panel. If you still don't understand maybe ask a new question and link your current file